# Postfix ignores -o settings in master.cf

Tags: postfix, smtp, smtpd

I'm configuring a Postfix with three services in master.cf. So far I learned from @anx (thank you so much!) that smtpd-based services in master.cf do not understand transport-related options. Only trivial-rewrite-based services support transport options so a custom trivial-rewrite service needs to be created and then the smtpd-based service can be bound to it with option rewrite_service_name:

```
smtp    inet    n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtp-in
  -o content_filter=
  -o mynetworks=/etc/postfix/exo_networks
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_sender,permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=>=TLSv1.2
  -o smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers=high
  -o rewrite_service_name=smtp-in-rewrite

submission      inet    n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o content_filter=
  -o smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o rewrite_service_name=submission-rewrite

2525    inet    n       -       n       -       100     smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks,no_milters
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8,10.10.10.0/24,10.10.20.0/24
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=
  -o rewrite_service_name=smtp-dmz-rewrite

smtp-in-rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
[...]

submission-rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission-rewrite
# default_transport was a mistake, should be transport_maps
#  -o default_transport=hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains
  -o transport_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains
  -o sender_dependent_relayhost_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_senders_relay
  -o relayhost=[3.3.3.1]

smtp-dmz-rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
[...]
```

In main.cf I've added a common relayhost to check if overriding it in master.cf works correctly:

```
relayhost=[4.4.4.1]
```

```
# /etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains
mydomain.com        relay:[1.1.1.1]
@mydomain.com        relay:[1.1.1.2]
*       relay:[1.1.1.3]
```

```
# /etc/postfix/transport_to_senders_relay
@mydomain.com       relay:[2.2.2.1]
mydomain.com relay:[2.2.2.2]
*       relay:[2.2.2.3]
```

If I sent via the transmission service an email from testa@mydomain.com to testa@mydomain.com, I'd expect the transmission-rewrite service to find a match in transport_to_exo_domains and therefore return 1.1.1.1 or 1.1.1.2 as next hop. That works (now, thx to @anx).
But then, already close to the finish line, smtp jumps in and sends the email to the main.cf-relayhost 4.4.4.1 instead of using the rewritten next hop 1.1.1.1.
Why does this happen and how can I reliably overwrite main.cf's relayhost? As far as I read the documentation of the smtp command, it doesn't support the relayhost option, so creating a custom smtp service won't work.

```
Jul  7 23:49:38 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[100828]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
Jul  7 23:49:38 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[100828]: connect from me.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de[188.194.X.Y]
Jul  7 23:49:38 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[100828]: Anonymous TLS connection established from me.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de[188.194.X.Y]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (128/128 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature ECDSA (P-384) server-digest SHA384
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[100833]: name_mask: ipv4
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/trivial-rewrite[100833]: inet_addr_local: configured 2 IPv4 addresses
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: process generation: 7 (7)
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: dict_open: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: dict_open: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_senders_relay
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: match_list_match: transport_maps: no match
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: transport_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains(0,lock|no_regsub|fold_fix|utf8_request): * = relay:[1.1.1.3]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: wildcard_{chan:hop}={relay:[1.1.1.3]}
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: address_verify_transport_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains(0,lock|no_regsub|fold_fix|utf8_request): * = relay:[1.1.1.3]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: wildcard_{chan:hop}={relay:[1.1.1.3]}
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr address = testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: sender
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: sender
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: (end)
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: match_list_match: mydomain.com: no match
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps: "<>": not found
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps: <>: not found
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: mail_addr_find: <> -> (not found)
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: transport_maps: testa@mydomain.com: not found
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: transport_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains(0,lock|no_regsub|fold_fix|utf8_request): mydomain.com = relay:[1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: mail_addr_find: testa@mydomain.com -> relay:[1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: `' -> `testa@mydomain.com' -> (`relay' `[1.1.1.1]' `testa@mydomain.com' `4096')
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr transport = relay
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr nexthop = [1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr recipient = testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: double-bounce
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: (end)
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: `local' `double-bounce' -> `double-bounce@smarthost.mydomain.com'
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr flags = 0
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr address = double-bounce@smarthost.mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: `local' `testa@mydomain.com' -> `testa@mydomain.com'
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr flags = 0
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr address = testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: sender
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: sender
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: testa@mydomain.com
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: submission-rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute name: address
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: input attribute value: testa@mydomain.com
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps: testa@mydomain.com: not found
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: match_list_match: mydomain.com: no match
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: sender_dependent_relayhost_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_senders_relay(0,lock|no_regsub|fold_fix|utf8_request): @mydomain.com = relay:[2.2.2.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: mail_addr_find: testa@mydomain.com -> relay:[2.2.2.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: transport_maps: testa@mydomain.com: not found
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: maps_find: transport_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_exo_domains(0,lock|no_regsub|fold_fix|utf8_request): mydomain.com = relay:[1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: mail_addr_find: testa@mydomain.com -> relay:[1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: `testa@mydomain.com' -> `testa@mydomain.com' -> (`relay' `[1.1.1.1]' `testa@mydomain.com' `4096')
[...]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr transport = relay
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr nexthop = [1.1.1.1]
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr recipient = testa@mydomain.com
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: send attr flags = 4096
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: master_notify: status 1
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[100828]: 640A34A99A: client=me.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de[188.194.X.Y], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=mfp1@mydomain.com
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/cleanup[100834]: 640A34A99A: message-id=<eddd4a91-3acf-fb28-a662-ab10c5801db2@mydomain.com>
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/qmgr[100822]: 640A34A99A: from=<testa@mydomain.com>, size=860, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  7 23:49:40 localhost postfix/submission/smtpd[100828]: disconnect from me.dynamic.kabel-deutschland.de[188.194.X.Y] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
Jul  7 23:49:45 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: connection closed fd 128
#
# So far everything looks promising now, but then smtp uses the default relayhost from main.cf instead of the correct next hop 1.1.1.1
#
Jul  7 23:50:10 localhost postfix/smtp[100836]: connect to 4.4.4.1[4.4.4.1]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  7 23:50:10 localhost postfix/smtp[100836]: 640A34A99A: to=<testa@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=30, delays=0.14/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 4.4.4.1[4.4.4.1]:25: Connection timed out)
Jul  7 23:51:25 localhost postfix/submission-rewrite/trivial-rewrite[100833]: idle timeout -- exiting
Jul  7 23:53:00 localhost postfix/anvil[100831]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (submission:188.194.X.Y) at Jul  7 23:49:38
Jul  7 23:53:00 localhost postfix/anvil[100831]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (submission:188.194.X.Y) at Jul  7 23:49:38
Jul  7 23:53:00 localhost postfix/anvil[100831]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jul  7 23:49:38
Jul  7 23:59:04 localhost postfix/qmgr[100822]: 640A34A99A: from=<testa@mydomain.com>, size=860, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul  7 23:59:34 localhost postfix/smtp[100852]: connect to 4.4.4.1[4.4.4.1]:25: Connection timed out
Jul  7 23:59:34 localhost postfix/smtp[100852]: 640A34A99A: to=<testa@mydomain.com>, relay=none, delay=595, delays=564/0.01/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to 4.4.4.1[4.4.4.1]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Once up and running, we'll deploy further changes through a git-Ansible-process and there will be a four eye maintenance to avoid misconfiguration. We haven't decided about all monitoring metrics, loop detection and bouncing directions yet.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this was persistent in the queue. With this log, I have no idea how to do it (other than running as many postfix instances as you have different sets of relay decisions you want to apply).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to override global defaults in `master.cf`, **you have to specify the options for the service that actually processes them**.

Refer to the manuals of the individual services to find out which options go where, in this case the [`trivial-rewrite`](https://www.postfix.org/trivial-rewrite.8.html) manual tells us the `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` and `relayhost` features are handled there.

Your smtpd service is ignoring your options just like it would ignore any other global options not meant for the smtpd service: it is talking to a separate service that has been started without these options.
Try with these modifications:

```
# instead of overriding options for the smtpd service, reference a customized variant of the service
[.. ] smtpd
 -o [..]
 -o rewrite_service_name=local-custom-rewrite
# duplicate this service ..
rewrite unix - - y - - trivial-rewrite
# .. under a new name and add your options there
local-custom-rewrite unix - - y - - trivial-rewrite
  -o sender_dependent_default_transport_maps=/etc/postfix/relay_transport_out
[..]
```

If you search for examples overriding `cleanup` service options, you will find more analogous configuration using the `cleanup_service_name` for the case where you want to override options of the service for specific smtpd instances.

---

Postfix services also accept the option -v (or multiple, to increase verbosity further), add that (like the -o options; at least for smtpd and trivial-rewrite) to see the fetched rewrite/resolve results.

Recommend you add options like `-o syslog_name=postfix/submission` to services started in multiple variations, otherwise it will be difficult to tell from logs which one sent a given log line.

---

If you suspect a problem with the lookup, test it isolated from the whole postfix service configuration, call `postmap -q "testa@mydomain.com" hash:/etc/postfix/transport_to_senders_relay` (see the *TABLE SEARCH ORDER* paragraph in the `man 5 transport` for which queries are tried).

> input attribute name: transport
> input attribute value: hash

I am not entirely certain I understand what you want the end result to behave like, but you need to pass `transport:nexthop` (or just `transport:`) to the `_transport` parameters, and `type:table` lookup to the `*_maps` parameters. I understand the log lines as the result of a type confusion, you must have attempted to specify a lookup where a direct transport specification was expected.

Comment: This answer is missing an explanation why the "unused parameter" feature (`src/postconf/postconf_unused.c`) does not warn about this. I don't know.